# Rebol / Red calling Headless Chrome on Windows

Tags: powershell, rebol, headless-browser, red

In Dos command to take screenshot, you can use (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome):

```
chrome --screenshot="C:\test\test.png" "http://google.com" --headless --disable-gpu
```

In Rebol, I can make it work only using powershell -command:

```
call {powershell -command "chrome --screenshot='C:\\test\\test.png' 'http://google.com' --headless --disable-gpu"}
```

In red I cannot make it work at all, did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works with the newest build, if you use the full path

```
>> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --screenshot=c:\test\test.png https://www.google.com --headless --disable-gpu"
== 1932
```

Comment: hope this will be fixed in the future because having to hard code a path is cumbersome.

Comment: I guess it's not an issue of **Red**, but of Windows or the installation of Chrome. I can not  start chrome from the cmd line with just **chrome**, but it works with **calc**